# Is the patent valid after 20 years

Tags: us5779129

In reference to the patent: [US5779129](https://www.google.com/patents/US5779129)

is the patent valid coz its more than 20 years now.Can we use the design for our production

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that for patents filed after 1995 that the expiration date is 20 years after the filing or priority date. In this case the filing date is January 24th, 1997 so this patent should have expired on January 24th, 2017. I looked in the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site to see if there were any patent term extensions and didn't find anything. Extensions are sometimes issued when there is an excessive delay in processing a patent application. You should be okay making a product exactly reproducing the invention described by this patent. I would caution that there is always the potential for other patents that might be refinements that are still in force. A good way to start looking for these would be to look at the [forward citations](https://www.google.com/patents/US5779129#forward-citations) for this patent. As DonQuiKong points out in his comments, there is at least a theoretical possibility that an older patent with a patent term extension might be relevant to your freedom to market this invention. I think this is  highly unlikely but not impossible.

Please understand that I am not a lawyer and this is not a legal opinion. As always, I suggest consulting with an actual patent attorney.

Comment: There could be an older patent still in force (term extension or late grant + 17yrs), theoretically.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Really? How? It was filed in 1997 and granted a mere 18 months later. I found no references to an extension in Pair.

Comment: imagine a patent from 1994 granted in 2005 or a patent from 1996 with 3 yrs extension

Comment: @DonQuiKong That I understand. What I don’t understand is how those situations apply to this patent.

Comment: there could be an older, broader patent forbidding the use of this patents technology. Not very likely, but possible.

Comment: @DonQuiKong This is a patent on a cardboard box. I’ve actually used boxes described by this patent. If you think your comment is important, I encourage you to add an answer.

Comment: "You should be okay making a product exactly reproducing the invention described by this patent." I just wanted to note that technically, that's not a given thing; because not only refinements could be still in force, but also older patents, especially as this one expired less than a year ago.

Comment: @DonQuiKong. Fine, I edited my answer to add this possibility.